Smarty Errors When Running job.process_mailing API
I'm getting some errors when running the schedule job for mail processing from our cron and via command line. I have tried with both the cv command and the drush command, both give similar errors pointing to Smarty. I cannot figure out what is going on. This is on Core 5.74.4 and Smarty 3 is turned on in the settings.
When I run: /usr/local/bin/cv api job.process_mailing --user=Feicron --cwd=/var/www/civicrm, I get:
In smarty_resource_recompiled.php(52) : eval()'d code line 35:

  Unsupported operand types: string - string

When I run: drush civicrm-api -u 1 job.process_mailing, I get:
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                                     [error]
Error: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/www/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_resource_recompiled.php(52) : eval()'d code, line 35

If I just run /usr/local/bin/cv api job.execute --cwd=/var/www/civicrm (without the user), it looks like it runs fine (shows a return with is_error = 0), but I then go into the process_mailing job log, and it shows this error:
Finished execution of Mailings scheduler with result: Failure, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM

That makes me think I have to include the user. But then I get the other errors. I'm not sure if this is a bug with mail processing and Smarty or if I'm just doing something wrong here. Any ideas?
I also now end up with a bunch of scheduled mailings in a "Running" state (though they never ran and sent) and don't know how to reset those. Any help would be appreciated.

The first thing I would do is switch to smarty 4 in civicrm.settings.php. At this point the answer to any question about smarty 3 is try 4. Just change the 3 to a 4.

@Demerit, this did not work. I changed to 4 and it gives the same error.

Based on the first error you probably have some code in the mailing it doesn't like. Are you using smarty in your civimails?
